# visual effect of a javafx button not on mouseclick

Tags: java, javafx

I have some javafx buttons which send a MQTT message to a broker. The message is send when the state of the buttons changes (ON to OFF or OFF to ON). The button also subscribes to the message it sends and I want to change the visual indication of the button when the message arrives.
The reason I want to do this is because the message can also come from another source (another device in the network). I want to show the state of the last message in the button.
How can I make sure the mouse event does not change the visual identification of the button and another event does change the visual identification of the button?

I now have this:

```
public class SlideCheckBox extends CheckBox implements RelayAwareInterface, MqttMessageSubscriberInterface {
    private String relayName;

    public SlideCheckBox(final String text) {
        super(text);
        getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/css/slidecheckbox.css").toExternalForm());
        setSkin(new SlideCheckBoxSkin(this));
    }

    public void withRelay(String relay) {
        relayName = "relay/" + relay;
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        if (message.equals("CLOSED") && !isArmed()) {
            fire();
        } else if (message.equals("OPEN") && isArmed()) {
            fire();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return relayName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getState() {
        return selectedProperty().getValue() ? "CLOSED" : "OPEN";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use a Task to load the message?

Comment: The message is received via the receiveMessage method.